# How do you convert from a multipolygon to a spatial polygons data frame

Tags: r, spatial

How do you convert from a `MULTIPOLYGON` to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` in `R`?

I can't find any other resources online and I attempted to discretise the same file that was a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, `XY` and `sfg` class, however, this led to a continuous loop of referencing the same polygon without accessing the individual points. I'm happy to provide any additional clarification and will appreciate any insight.

A sample of one of the outputs for the multipolygon `Ref_circles` to show formatting is given as:

```
Ref_circles[1]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
       [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 51.62730 4.340600
[2,] 51.62549 4.343550
[3,] 51.61800 4.357353
[4,] 51.61124 4.371529
[5,] 51.60523 4.386039
[6,] 51.59998 4.400845
...
[311,] 51.63570 4.322473
[312,] 51.62894 4.336649
[313,] 51.62730 4.340600
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first question to you would be: why do you want to convert from an `sf` object (MULTIPOLYGON) to an `sp` object (SpatialPolygonDataFrame), as `sf` supersedes `sp`?

There are probably ways to achieve your end goal staying within the `sf` library without having to do this conversion.

If you still want to do it, it will be along the lines of

```
library(sf)
library(sp)

## using a MULTIPOLYGON data set supplied with library(sf)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

## convert the geometry of the `sf` object to SpatialPolygons
spd <- sf::as_Spatial(st_geometry(nc), IDs = as.character(1:nrow(nc)))

class(spd)
# [1] "SpatialPolygons"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"

## grab the data from the sf object
df <- nc
df$geometry <- NULL
df <- as.data.frame(df)

## create the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
spd <- sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spd, data = df)

class(spd)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"

head(spd@data)
# AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79
# 1 0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1      10  1364     0      19
# 2 0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0      10   542     3      12
# 3 0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5     208  3616     6     260
# 4 0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1     123   830     2     145
# 5 0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9    1066  1606     3    1197
# 6 0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7     954  1838     5    1237
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to find the area of overlap between a series of circles that I setup using `st_buffer(References_coord, dist = 0.3)`, and a Voronoi diagram generated using `st_voronoi(Hubs_coord)`. For some reason when using `st_intersection` there is no output area and so I'm trying to use the `intersect` function, which requires an `sp` format. I know it seems contrived but it's a problem I've been struggling to deal with  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269498/determining-areas-on-a-voronoi-diagram-around-a-point